# Hidden Div's not hiding over 3g network yet works fine on wi-fi

Tags: php, css, html, hidden

I have seen very similar posts on here but not quite the same.
Page loads fine over wi-fi, not over 3g.
issue.
I have hidden div's which should call a seperate inc file via php, problem is they are all being loaded at once & the css script file is being ignored.  any ideas,  would it help if I shortened the css file and just had a specific one just for my hidden divs?

Web page with hidden div's (no spaces in the div id's)

```
<div id="PopUp1"  class="PopUp1">
    <?php include "scripts/wsr/driver1.inc"?> 
    <div style='text-align: right;'>
        <a onmouseover='this.style.cursor="pointer"'
           style='font-size: 12px;'
           onfocus='this.blur();'
           onclick="document.getElementById('PopUp1').style.display = 'none'">
            <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
                Close
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An html div "calls an inc"? Huh?

Comment: What is your platform? Are you using it on a mobile device? Which?

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess:  The CSS or similar is cached on the 3G providers webcache -- so you are actually getting an old version (say a version from within the last 24 hours)

Try to cache-bust by change the name of the CSS and other files loaded and it will probably all start working

Comment: That's my guess as well.  I don't imagine it's *actually* ignoring the CSS, otherwise you'd have a complete render failure.  An outdated copy matches the symptoms most closely.

Comment: thanks guys but it is just displaying the content rather than hiding it, I will try the cache bust thanks.

Comment: also,  is it bad form to call an inc inside a div?  I'm pretty new to it and wanted to load as little as possible on the first page, I figured the div calling the inc was a good way around this... or nt it seems?

Comment: also  it works fine on a "3" 3g card in an IPAD  but not on an o2 3g on an Iphone...

Comment: ok guys, you could be right. I just (inventively renamed the file to cachebust.php, this cannot be found over 3g (404 error)  yet is found on wi-fi.. could be right, will update in a day or so many thanks for your help so far

Comment: Nope, Still doesn't do it, its still showing what should be hidden Divs but only over 3g (iphone) even after renaming and uploading  and renaming newer versions...

Comment: though, as you rightly point out, the rest of the styling is fine. so its not ignoring the file,  just the divs

Comment: but did you rename the css files as well or just the php?  Anyway, the caching should not be around after days, so something else is wrong, and we have too little info without the rest of the code to help

Answer (score 1):

**Late reply - PHP and Jquery-min-1.5 and above**

Recently I encountered a similar problem when using PHP and Jquery-min-1.5.X (and above).

When developing a eCommerce system for a client, I implemented a carousel, with the source code placed in PHP file and powered by Jquery-min-1.5.2.js placed locally on the server.

**Problems encountered:**
When using mobile devices (ie iPhone, iPad etc) connected via wifi/ cable the carousel displayed correctly. Tethering the website through 3G via Orange, Vodafone again the site displayed correctly.

However if I tethered the website via O2 or T-Mobile to a iPhone or iPad the ajax function failed to load correctly thus causing errors in the debug console.

MD5 SUM reveals differences in how data is pulled from the server (comparison between wifi and tethering O2) - which concludes this is not a CSS/ Cache error.

Change "script" directory from local to point at Google Ajax Library and the carousel displays correctly.

In conclusion the error is caused by a server proxy error - only apparent with O2 and T-Mobile.

When testing this theory I used the iPhone debug console on both Orange and O2 networks. Orange revealed no errors throughout the testing phase. O2 revealed error prior to the above being carried out, following the changes the errors were resolved.